# Will a GTX 650TI work on a HP Prodesk 600 G1?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Will this graphics card work? It has a Intel g3220 with 3ghz and 8gb of ram. Thanks

Comment: @Ramhound you have to remember not everyone is technical and knows what to look for.

Comment: @Keltari - While that is the case, I literally, indicated what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

No.  That card will not work in your desktop.

According to [HP's product description](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03846648#AbT8) I found, the HP ProDesk 600 G1 has a 240 watt power supply.

According to [NVidia's website](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-650ti/specifications), the GTX 650 Ti requires the system to have a minimum of 400 watts.

This means you would have to replace the PSU with a more powerful one, in order to get the graphics card to work.

Additionally, in the specifications, the HP ProDesk 600 G1 is a small form factor PC.  I did not find any information regarding if the power supply is a standard ATX or if it is a custom PSU form factor.  You might have to contact HP to see if there are more powerful PSU options that would fit in your PCs case.

I assume you are interested in upgrading for gaming.  This is not a PC I would invest money upgrading.  It is a fairly old, low power PC, not suited for gaming.  If I were you and money was a factor, I would save some money and invest in a modern budget gaming PC, or in a used used higher end gaming PC.